# Is there a way to get a short CVS status from command line?

Tags: cvs

When doing a `cvs update`, you get a nice summary of the state of the repository, for example:

```
M src/file1.txt
M src/file2.txt
C src/file3.txt
A src/file4.txt
? src/file5.txt
```

Is there a way to get this without actually updating? I know there is `cvs status`, but this is way to verbose:

```
===================================================================
File: file6.txt        Status: Up-to-date

Working revision:    1.2
Repository revision: 1.2     /var/cvs/cvsroot/file6.txt,v
Sticky Tag:          (none)
Sticky Date:         (none)
Sticky Options:      (none)
```

I could of course make a script to do the transformation from the latter to the former, but it seems a waste of time since cvs can obviously produce the former.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the -n flag to get the update output without actually updating the files. You can also add -q (quiet) to suppress any server messages.

```
cvs -q -n update
```

Comment: "cvs -n update" is a great solution for previewing a CVS update (thank you), but doesn't seem to work with tags.  For example, "cvs -n update -dP -r DRUPAL-5-15" gives "cvs [update aborted]: no such tag `DRUPAL-5-13'", but the tag is definitely valid, as "cvs update -dP -r DRUPAL-5-15" works fine.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I whimper with git-withdrawl a bit less after adding `alias cvs-st="cvs -q -n update"`

Answer (score 4):

@jmcnamara: Good tip!

And all this time I've been using this bash script:

```
cvs -q status "$@" | grep '^[?F]' | grep -v 'Up-to-date'
```

Answer (score 4):

I have some aliases, that may be useful for somebody:

```
alias cvsstatus_command='cvs -q status | grep "^[?F]" | grep -v "Up-to-date" | \
    grep -v "\.so" | grep -v "\.[c]*project"'

alias cvsstatus_color='nawk '"'"'BEGIN \
    { \
        arr["Needs Merge"] = "0;31"; \
        arr["Needs Patch"] = "1;31"; \
        arr["conflicts"] = "1;33"; \
        arr["Locally Modified"] = "0;33"; \
        arr["Locally Added"] = "0;32" \
    } \
    { \
        l = $0; \
        for (pattern in arr) { \
            gsub(".*" pattern ".*", "\033[" arr[pattern] "m&\033[0m", l); \
        } \
        print l; \
    }'"'"

alias cvsstatus='cvsstatus_command | cvsstatus_color'
```

This will display only file names and their status, ignore all up-to-date files, remove all eclipse project files and shared objects and will also **print the lines in different colors, depending on the status** (for example, I have orange for locally modified; red for files, needing merge; green for locally added, etc)

Comment: Excellent approach! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CVSNT you can also just do `cvs status -q` which will also produce much briefer output than the regular status command (also just one line per file). With more recent versions you can even do `cvs status -qq` which will skip the up-to-date files.