# Easiest way to find CVS not added files and added but not committed files

Tags: cvs

I am using cvs for my project . I have already added and committed some files before . After that I have modified , added , committed . 
But now I am not sure if every file existing in the project was added  and also if every added file was committed .
So how to find the files which

- were not at all added (but exist in the local repo )
- added  but not committed

Edit :  There are many files . so cvs log ,cvs log filename  would not be so easier

Comment: What version control software are you using? For example, git or mercurial?

Comment: @Mai : As mentioned in question , I am using cvs

Comment: sorry, I read csv for some reason-.-...

Comment: @Mai : okay . So any idea on above question ?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Is there a way to get a short CVS status from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211819/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-short-cvs-status-from-command-line)

Comment: But are u sure that it considers the files which are not at all added?                
Moreover , in that question cvs status -qq is suggested which doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information in this answer was gleaned from the output of:

```
cvs -H update
```

The solution is:

```
cvs -nq update
```

Files present in the local workspace not yet added appear in the output as:

```
? file
```

The description from CVS help explains:

```
  file  is  in  your working directory, but does not correspond to anyâ
  thing in the source repository, and is not in the list of  files  for
  cvs  to  ignore  (see  the description of the -I option, and see node
  'cvsignore' in the CVS manual).
```

Files added but not committed appear in the output like this:

```
A file
```

The CVS help description goes on to say:

```
  The file has been added to your private copy of the sources, and will
  be  added  to  the source repository when you run commit on the file.
  This is a reminder to you that the file needs to be committed.
```

Exceptions do apply in the case of files not added yet:

- *.cvsignore* files in the local workspace suppress appearance of files in the same directory that have not yet been added to cvs control.
- The CVSROOT/cvsignore repository configuration file does the same thing but it affects the entire workspace (all directories).
- At least on some platforms, there appear to be implicit ignores for certain binary files like those that match a glob of "*.exe".